# Different Matlab code listings environment in same document with Matlab-prettifier

Tags: listings, lstdefinestyle, matlab-prettifier

I wanted to be able to have different Matlab code listings in the same document.  The first three listings are from the [solution found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70145/lstlistings-framed-code).

How do I get rid of the thin lined boxes in the first 3 Matlab code settings, while still keeping the thin box around the last `lstlisting`:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}

\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
numbersep=8pt,
language=Matlab
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{
    arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
    listing only,
    listing style=mystyle,
    title=#2,
    #1
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}{}
%% Accuracy Calculation
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}[hbox]{}
%% Accuracy Calculation
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow]{Accuracy Calculation}
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100
\end{mylisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[
backgroundcolor=\color{blue!05},
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small
]
%% Accuracy Calculation
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You load the `mcode` package with the `framed` option, which adds the thin (undesired) frame around the code. Your `mylisting` environment is a color box from the `tcolorbox` package, which adds *another* frame around it. This is why you have the two frames.

To remove the inner frames, simply remove the `framed` option when loading `mcode`:

```
\usepackage[numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
```

[image: result]

**Remark:** you are using two different packages for the same purpose. If you don't watch out, you *will* get inconsistent output. As both these packages use `listings` in the background, they have undesired interactions: for example by removing `framed` from the `mcode` package, suddenly the line numbers in the `matlab-prettifier` listing are *outside* of the frame - even though you didn't change anything! Please, try to decide for one package<sup>1</sup> and stick to that.
You *can* setup `matlab-prettifier` to look like your `mcode` listings now, or the other way around.

<sup>1</sup> `matlab-prettifier` is newer and has more features than `mcode`, and it comes with most standard LaTeX installations