# Move listing numbers outside of framed box in Matlab Prettifier

Tags: matlab, matlab-prettifier

The question is building off the [solution give here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340363/different-matlab-code-listings-environment-in-same-document-with-matlab-prettifi/340455#340455).

How do you remove the `mcode` package so that listings 1 - 3 will have the Matlab code that resembles the last listing and also contain the line numbers outside of the box :

[image]

Here is the original solution as given by [hbaderts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/65692/hbaderts):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}

\usepackage[numbered,framed,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{matlab-prettifier}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
numbersep=8pt,
%language=Matlab,
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
frame=none
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{
    arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
    listing only,
    colback=blue!10,
    colbacktitle=blue!75!black,
    listing style=mystyle,
    title=#2,
    #1
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}{}
%% Accuracy Calculation
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}[hbox]{}
%% Accuracy Calculation
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow]{Accuracy Calculation}
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100

%% Save data to be used in pgfplots
switch nn
    case 1
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN1.dat','w');
    case 2
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN2.dat','w');
end
\end{mylisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[
backgroundcolor=\color{blue!05},
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small
]
%% Accuracy Calculation
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100

%% Save data to be used in pgfplots
switch nn
    case 1
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN1.dat','w');
    case 2
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN2.dat','w');
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to move the numbers, a quick hack could be to use `numbersep=25pt` or similar. However this will not change the margins around the code block, they will still be different then in the last code block.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}

\usepackage[numbered,framed,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{matlab-prettifier}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
numbersep=8pt,
%language=Matlab,
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
numbersep=25pt,
frame=none
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{
    arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
    listing only,
    colback=blue!10,
    colbacktitle=blue!75!black,
    listing style=mystyle,
    title=#2,
    #1
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}{}
%% Accuracy Calculation
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}[hbox]{}
%% Accuracy Calculation
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow]{Accuracy Calculation}
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100

%% Save data to be used in pgfplots
switch nn
    case 1
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN1.dat','w');
    case 2
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN2.dat','w');
end
\end{mylisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[
backgroundcolor=\color{blue!05},
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small
]
%% Accuracy Calculation
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100

%% Save data to be used in pgfplots
switch nn
    case 1
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN1.dat','w');
    case 2
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN2.dat','w');
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

For the first box, the margins can be adjusted as the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}

\usepackage[numbered,framed,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{matlab-prettifier}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
numbersep=8pt,
%language=Matlab,
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
xleftmargin=-12pt,
aboveskip=-6pt,
belowskip=-6pt,
frame=none
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{
    arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
    listing only,
    colback=blue!10,
    colbacktitle=blue!75!black,
    listing style=mystyle,
    title=#2,
    #1
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}{}
%% Accuracy Calculation
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}[hbox]{}
%% Accuracy Calculation
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow]{Accuracy Calculation}
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100

%% Save data to be used in pgfplots
switch nn
    case 1
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN1.dat','w');
    case 2
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN2.dat','w');
end
\end{mylisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[
backgroundcolor=\color{blue!05},
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small
]
%% Accuracy Calculation
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100

%% Save data to be used in pgfplots
switch nn
    case 1
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN1.dat','w');
    case 2
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN2.dat','w');
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input!  Is there a way to adjust the margin for the text in the block also?  Thanks.

Comment: @Joe Is it enough to modify them for your first code block? The one without `[hbox]`

Comment: my apologies, but I do not understand your question...please tell me what you meant?  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe See the edit to my answer. I mean that I can modify the margins of the first code block, but not of the others which use `hbox`.