# Input file path in modified listing environment

Tags: lstdefinestyle

I have a [modified environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70145/lstlistings-framed-code) for a listing called `mylisting`.  I wanted to know how to include the path to the file to be used in the `mylisting` environment?

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{HOG_test.m}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write('Case insensitive ');
WritE('Pascal keywords.');
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[numbered,framed,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{matlab-prettifier}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
numbersep=8pt,
%language=Matlab,
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
numbersep=25pt,
frame=none
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{
    arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
    listing only,
    colback=blue!10,
    colbacktitle=blue!75!black,
    listing style=mystyle,
    title=#2,
    #1
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow]{Accuracy Calculation}
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100

%% Save data to be used in pgfplots
switch nn
    case 1
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN1.dat','w');
    case 2
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN2.dat','w');
end
\end{mylisting}


\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow]{Accuracy Calculation}

% How to get "HOG_test.m" code to appear in the mylisting???
\end{mylisting}]
\lstinputlisting{HOG_test.m}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined your new environment by means of the command `\newtcblisting`.
That command does not come from the listings package. 
It comes from the tcolorbox package.

Therefore take advantage also of the other features/macros provided by the tcolorbox package:

Instead of the `\lstinputlisting`-command from the listings package use
the `\tcbinputlisting`-command from the tcolorbox package for displaying code that is stored in external files.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{HOG_test.m}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write('Case insensitive ');
WritE('Pascal keywords.');
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[numbered,framed,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{matlab-prettifier}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\small,
  numbersep=8pt,
  %language=Matlab,
  style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  numbersep=25pt,
  frame=none
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{%
  arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
  listing only,
  colback=blue!10,
  colbacktitle=blue!75!black,
  listing style=mystyle,
  title=#2,
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow]{Accuracy Calculation}
Equal_Rows = find(diff(matrix_rec,[],2) == 0);
percent_success = (size(Equal_Rows,1)/numFolders) * 100

%% Save data to be used in pgfplots
switch nn
    case 1
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN1.dat','w');
    case 2
        fileID = fopen('PCA_KNN2.dat','w');
end
\end{mylisting}


\tcbinputlisting{%
   arc=0pt, 
   outer arc=0pt,
   listing only,
   colback=blue!10,
   colbacktitle=blue!75!black,
   listing style=mystyle,
   title=Accuracy Calculation,
   hbox,
   enhanced,
   drop shadow,
   listing file=HOG_test.m
}

\end{document}
```