# Box around the code?

Tags: listings, code, quoting, box

I have a piece of code written as:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
  code
\end{lstlisting}
```

I want to put a box, around the code.

I have already read this question [Source code listing with frame around code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14967/source-code-listing-with-frame-around-code)

But I only want a simple box, not the title at the beginning

Comment: Read the manual at page 17: add `[frame=single]` option. (The manual is available using `texdoc listings` or here: https://ctan.org/pkg/listings?lang=en)

Comment: @Rmano I haven't found any clearly related question except https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70145/82917 which is however closed as off-topic. I'd say go on and write an answer.

Comment: @campa done. MementoMori: in my answer you have a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) --- please use a similar thing when posting your next question(s)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is around page 17 of the manual.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
    This is my
    code
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

In the manual you have a lot of possible options for the frame, and some warning on how to tweak things if the frames are "wrong" --- it is a good idea to read it!